# playing and recording with two microphones simultaneously matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, record, playback

I try to play white noise and record at the same time with two microphones which is connected to same sound card. I am using wavplay and wavrecord for simultaneous record and it is working for a single microphone. I don't know how to add second microphone to my code, i tried adding second wav record but it plotted the first record result. I hope I could explain the problem and can get some help.

```
    a= randn (1,44100);
    b = zeros (1, length (a)');
    c= [a;b];
    wavplay (c',44100,'async');
    r = wavrecord (length (c),44100,1,'int16');
```

this is for 1 mic and it is working. but i can't add second mic in that code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't think wavrecord supports multiple devices.  It's been deprecated in favor of [audiorecorder](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiorecorder.html).

Audio recorder takes an additional argument for the audio device

`recorder = audiorecorder(Fs,nBits,nChannels,ID)`

You can get the ID from the `audiodevinfo` command, see the [docs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audiodevinfo.html).

If you run into trouble with devices, [this article](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/54191-record-multiple-microphones-simultaneously) may help.

Comment: thanks for response. I am able to record with second microphone via audio recorder. but in that case I am not able to play and record at the same time. first my loudspeaker plays the white noise and then the microphones start recording.